# Mapbox/Leafet Popups - Need difference min-heights for popups

Tags: css, leaflet, mapbox

I'm creating a map that allows the user to select a zip code from the left side, and then have it filled in on the map itself.  Once the user clicks the shaded zip code, a popup appears with information about that zip (see below):

[image]

At the same time, I'm dropping markers on surrounding competitors.  When the user clicks a marker, the popup will appear with the competitors' name, and franchise car they sell (see below):

[image]

In order to make sure that the ZIP code information fit in the popup area (I had some issues where the popup would not expand with the contained div), I created a style class to ensure the popup was large enough:

```
div.leaflet-popup-content {
min-height: 400px;
```

}

The bad news is, now that style is being applied to my competitor pins and it looks terrible.

Is there a way to set the css from within the bindpopup area of the declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than making all popups 400px high by default, you can put your popup content inside a `div` with its own css class, then set the properties for that class however you like. For example, if you have two GeoJSON point layers (let's call them `points1` and `points2`), and you want to make the popups for `points1` 400px tall:

```
var tallPoints = L.geoJson(points1, {onEachFeature: onEachTall}).addTo(map);
var shortPoints = L.geoJson(points2, {onEachFeature: onEachShort}).addTo(map);

function onEachTall(feature, layer) {
  layer.bindPopup('<div class="tallPop">Tall Popup is Tall</div>');
}

function onEachShort(feature, layer) {
  layer.bindPopup('<div class="shortPop">Short Popup is not so Tall</div>');
}
```

Where the css for the `tallPop` class is:

```
.tallPop {
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

Here is an example fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/nez8zrnm/

Comment: Your answer worked, but I have since found an even easier solution... setting the style for the .leaflet-popup-content class to "display: inline-block;" does the trick